# ternary with string in asp net mvc razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ternary

I have

```
<h3 class="panel-title">
            "@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OST"] == "true" ? "Out-of-State Travel" : "Out-Service Training/Out-of-State Travel")"
        </h3>
```

however it is rendering with the quotes

it shows up as "Out of State Travel". or "Out-Service Training/Out-of-State Travel"

Comment: Why do you have `"` before @?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the ternary operation:

```
@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OST"] == "true" ? "Out-of-State Travel" : "Out-Service Training/Out-of-State Travel")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the quotes:

```
<h3 class="panel-title">
            @(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OST"] == "true" ? "Out-of-State Travel" : "Out-Service Training/Out-of-State Travel")
        </h3>
```